# What does the 'shell' argument in subprocess mean on Windows?

Tags: python, subprocess

The docs for the subprocess module state that 'If *shell* is True, the specified command will be executed through the shell'. What does this mean in practice, on a Windows OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute an external process, the command you want may look something like "foo arg1 arg2 arg3". If "foo" is an executable, that is what gets executed and given the arguments.

However, often it is the case that "foo" is actually a script of some sort, or maybe a command that is built-in to the shell and not an actual executable file on disk. In this case the system can't execute "foo" directly because, strictly speaking, these sorts of things aren't executable. They need some sort of "shell" to execute them. On *nix systems this shell is typically (but not necessarily) /bin/sh. On windows it will typically be cmd.exe (or whatever is stored in the COMSPEC environment variable).

This parameter lets you define what shell you wish to use to execute your command, for the relatively rare case when you don't want the default.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the command will be executed using the program specified in the `COMSPEC` environment variable. Usually `cmd.exe`.

To be exact, subprocess calls the [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) windows api function, passing `"cmd.exe /c " + args` as the `lpCommandLine` argument.

If shell==False, the `lpCommandLine` argument to CreateProcess is simply `args`.

Answer (score 0):

In [using-the-subprocess-module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module), there is an explicit paragraph:

> The executable argument specifies the program to execute. It is very seldom needed: Usually, the program to execute is defined by the args argument. If shell=True, the executable argument specifies which shell to use. On Unix, the default shell is /bin/sh. **On Windows, the default shell is specified by the COMSPEC environment variable.**

*Windows example* - the shell (`cmd.exe`) command `date -t` will not be recognized without the shell:

```
>>> p=subprocess.Popen(["date", "/t"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 804, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>>
```

Using a shell, all is well:

```
>>> p=subprocess.Popen(["date", "/t"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.communicate()
('Wed 04/22/2009 \r\n', None)
>>>
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for more than just a regurgitation of the documentation. I think they don't grok the whole concept of a shell in this context and are looking for a little more than what the documentation gives.

Comment: @BryanOakley - I disagree. This is exactly what I needed. I was looking through the documentation and was unable to find the section which went into detail on what `shell=True` or `shell=False` does until I found gimel's answer here which pulled it out and emphasized different parts.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was said in other answers, it is useful in practice if you want to open a file in the default viewer for that file type.  For instance, if you want to open an HTML or PDF file, but will not know which browser or viewer is installed on the systems it will be run on, or have no guarantees as to the path to the executable, you can simply pass the file name as the only argument for the args field, then set shell=True.  This will have Windows use whatever program is associated with that file type.
One caveat, if the path to your file has spaces, you need to surround it with two ".

eg.

```
path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Bob\\Desktop\\New Folder\\README.txt"
subprocess.call('""' + path + '""', shell = True)
```

Comment: os.startfile is a better method for doing this.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't know that even existed.  I dug around for hours on Google and this was the best I could find.